# Is Perl Do-While considered Best Practice (AKA professional coding standard) or should alternatives be used?

Tags: perl

Is using Do-While considered Best Practice (AKA professional coding standard) when programming in Perl?

```
my $continue = 1;
do {
    # When time to break the loop.
    $continue = 0;
} while ($continue);
```

Or should an alternative be used such as ...

```
MYLOOP: while(1){
    # When time to break the loop.
    last MYLOOP;
}
```

Comment: @user4035 `last` will exit the loop.

Comment: @Slade ok, I read the docs. Label is not necessary here - he has just 1 loop. Thx!

Comment: @user4035 Perl Best Practices recommends using labels for any loop that uses `next`, `last`, or `redo`; the justification is that it helps convey intent (e.g. `next LINE if (...);` clearly indicates the loop is iterating over the lines of a file), as well as making the flow-modifying statements more visibly distinct. In fact, Perl even labels the implicit loop when you use the `-n` or `-p` switches with `LINE:`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [`while`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) loop.

The [`do BLOCK`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) construct does not count as a loop, and so loop control statements don't work for it:

> - `do BLOCK`
>
>   Not really a function. Returns the value of the last command in the sequence of commands indicated by `BLOCK`. When modified by the [`while`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) or [`until`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/until.html) loop modifier, executes the `BLOCK` once before testing the loop condition. (On other statements the loop modifiers test the conditional first.)
>
>   `do BLOCK` does *not* count as a loop, so the loop control statements [`next`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html), [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html), or [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) cannot be used to leave or restart the block. See [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) for alternative strategies.

Comment: You answer is very knowledgable and very well referenced, but the question asks - Is using do-while considered best practice (AKA professional coding standard)?

Comment: I would never use a `do-while` for the reason stated above.  Instead, I would use a `while () { ... last if COND; }`